# What is the wmdistance for a word2vec model and for a doc2vec model in gensim?

Tags: gensim

I want to compare the similarity between two strings, I can calculate the wmd distance with a word2vec model or with a doc2vec model in gensim. But I could not understand how does wmd work for a doc2vec model.

```
def preprocess(doc):    
    return doc.lower().split()

s1 = 'i would like five rooms'
s2 = 'i would like four rooms'
s1 = preprocess(s1)
s2 = preprocess(s2)

model1 = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(word2vec_model, binary = False) 
d1 = model1.wmdistance(s1, s2)
print('wmd distance using a word2vec model:', d1)

model2 = gensim.models.Doc2Vec.load(doc2vec_model)
d2 = model2.wmdistance(s1, s2)
print('wmd distance using a doc2vec model:', d2)

# wmd distance using a word2vec model: 0.502799493163681
# wmd distance using a doc2vec model: 0.008121068463511764
```

Does wmd still take the word embeddings for each word from the doc2vec model as it does with a word2vec model? Is there no difference with a word2vec model or a doc2vec model to calculate the wmd distance? In the below example, the wmd distances calculated from these 2 models are very different, why is this? I understand how wmd works generally for two sentences, but I just cannot figure out how it works for a doc2vec model. I would appreciate it if someone can help me understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Word Mover's Distance always works based on the individual word-vectors for the words in a text.

The gensim `Doc2Vec` class includes a `wmdistance()` method, inherited from the same superclass as `Word2Vec`, for reasons of historic code-sharing. But, in recent gensim versions, you should be receiving a deprecation-warning if you use that method. The proper way to call it would be via the model's `wv` property  – which will be an instance of `KeyedVectors` – which should make it clear the same thing is happening in either case: the individual word-vectors are being consulted & fed into the same WMD algorithm.

But, note that only some `Doc2Vec` modes (but not all!) will train-up useful word-vectors. And unfortunately, again for reasons of historic code-sharing, the `Doc2Vec` mode that doesn't train word-vectors (plain PV-DBOW, `dm=0`) will still leave randomly initialized word-vectors in the `model.wv` property.

From the results you show, one or the other of the models you're using may be missing relevant words, or severely underpowered. If they both had similarly-well-trained word-vectors for all words in your test texts, I'd expect the WMD results to be more similar.